# Creating square shapes in bootstrap based on fluid span's width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) using the fluid-row (or even regular 'row') grid system with responsive design, how can I get the elements to have the same height as they do width?

In other words, is it possible to have the height of a `.span` element match it's assigned width based on the responsive css design in Bootstrap?

Or would this need to be done in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting height = 100% or Auto.

Comment: yes, unfortunately, the `.span` elements would then fill their container to it's 100% height. and Auto would set them to fill their own content.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.? finally what happened did you clear it?